# .htaccess How to allow php execution only in one directory? + security questions

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, security, mod-rewrite

I'm a junior PHP developer. Please, can you clarify for me some security questions?

Assuming I use hosting with Apache and the following structure of directories:

```
example.com/
    [550] application/              - php files of the site
    [440] libs/                     - 3rd party libs
    [770] logs/                     - access and error logs
    [770] www/                      - web root
        [444] .htaccess
        [440] entry_points/         - entry points for all "end"s of the site
            [440] frontend.php
            [440] cabinet.php
            [440] manager.php
        [444] themes/               - ui themes
            [444] {theme}/
                [444] css/
                [444] js/
                [444] img/
        [774] files/                - files like images, pdfs and so on
```

Questions:

1. Are these access rights good for files and directories? I don't fully understand meaning of Linux rights system in context of web server.
2. Are there some ways to hide entry scripts from a web user? I've already tried to move entry_points directory one level up and out of web access. But mod_rewrite generates an error in this case.
3. **themes** directory can contain only css, js, jpg and png files. **files** directory can contain only some "regular" file types like jpg, png, pdf, xls and so on. **entry_points** directory is the only web accessible directory which can legally contain a predefined set of "safe" executable php scripts. All these scripts are used by mod_rewrite. So, a direct access to them is unwanted. So, how can I allow execution of ANY php code in public area **ONLY** in "entry_points" directory?
4. Is it better to use one entry script (like index.php) with additional regex checks inside or separate scripts and choose between them with mod_rewrite?
5. Do you have any suggestions according to the structure of files and directories?
6. Are there any other tips to increase security of the site? I know that I can Google about security. But assuming I kinda newbee in this topic I'm afraid that I can accidentally find something like "anti-patterns" (sorry for my English, I can not find more suitable word).

**Update:** To be more specific, the main question is 3 - How to allow php execution only in one directory (entry_points in this case)?

Comment: Please do not post multi-question questions. They are too broad and have to be closed.

Comment: Question 1: http://serverfault.com/questions/357108/what-permissions-should-my-website-files-folders-have-on-a-linux-webserver - Question 2: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html - Question 3: mod_rewrite with `[F]`? - Question 4/5: Off-topic for StackOverflow, primarily opinion based - Question 6: Off-topic as it does not focus on a specific problem.

Comment: Hello, @Sumurai8. I'm trying not to post multiple questions at once. The main question is 3rd - how to allow execution of any PHP code only in one directory? The other questions were born in process of writing this post.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure that "mod_rewrite with [F]" is fully suitable to restrict PHP script execution in all other directories except "entry_points". What if an evil guy will create a new directory in the web root somehow? As I understand, this trick relies on file extension (.php or something like that). As I know, there are some possibilities to inject an evil code into HTML files, into images and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Have the following directives in a .htaccess file in your www-root, behind any rule that would rewrite an url to a file in entry_points. It will send a forbidden status code when a file is requested that contains ".php" that is not inside the entry_points subfolder.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^entry_points/
RewriteRule \.php - [F,L]
```

The way Apache works, is that it checks for any extension a file has, and executes a handler for that file if one is defined. On a normal installation, only files that contain a `.php` extension will invoke the php interpreter. A file called `example.php.old.2011.12.02` still contains the php extension, as well as a bunch of other extensions.

You should not rely on this alone however. You should make sure that your upload script will not allow people to upload php files, or force files to be saved outside the /files/ folder.

---

To prevent people from directly accessing scripts in the entry_points folder, you can use mod_rewrite, or use mod_authz_host. Using mod_rewrite does not solely allow you to block access, but allows you to redirect users too for example. A simple way to send a forbidden status code when someone tries to access a script in entry_points directly is:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /entry_points/
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

Using `%{THE_REQUEST}` we ensure that the external request contained that text. If we would not do that and use `%{REQUEST_URI}` instead, it would also match when we rewrite to such a script. That is not our intention (obviously).